# How to model when you could have many (thousands of) attributes to a table (product)?

Tags: database-design

We have a main table, let's say, Product. It has several general attributes like 'Product Name', Manufacturer ID, etc. As of now, all these attributes are implemented in the data model as columns to the Product.

Now we have a new requirement where there could be thousands of attributes. Color, size, weight, dimensions, style, etc. Each of these attributes have pre-defined values. Like color can only be ('green', 'yellow', 'red'). The value set is defined for each attribute. But there could be thousands of attributes and each attribute could have thousands of pre-defined values.

So, for this new feature, we defined these attributes as 'row values' instead of 'columns'.

**Something like this:**

---

### **Product Table**

```
ProductID   Name    Date_Created
1           Candy     some date
2           Shirt     some date 
3           Pants     some date
```

---

---

### **Attribute Table**

```
AttributeID   Name
1             Color
2             Dimension
3             Weight
```

---

---

### **AttributeValue Table**

```
AttributeValueID   AttributeID    Value
1                  1              Green
2                  1              Yellow
3                  1              Red
4                  2              11x11
5                  2              12x12
6                  2              13x13
7                  3              1 lb
8                  3              2 lb
9                  3              3 lb
```

---

Now to create association between Product Table and Attribute table, we have an association table called 'ProductAttributes'

---

### **ProductAttributes Table**

```
ProductAttributeId      ProductID      AttributeID      AttributeValueID
1                           1              1                   1
2                           1              2                   4
3                           1              3                   9
4                           2              1                   2
5                           2              3                   8
6                           3              3                   8
```

---

Does this model make sense? Could you suggest any improvements? As of now this ProductAttributes Table is expected to grow to 200 Million as there are a more than 100K attributes.

**Other points:**
1. A product could have more than one attribute
2. A product could have more than one of the same attribute. A shirt is both 'brown' and 'green'
3. All Attributes and its Values have to be pre-defined (loaded from text file)
4. Once the data is loaded (once every few months), there is heavy SELECTing. So the model needs to be **read-optimized**.

Comment: You should check out how Magento is built. It works on much the same principles - an EAV (Entity-Attribute-Value) structure.

Comment: Yes, it has a name: Entity-Attribute-Value. And it's an anti-pattern.

Comment: @Colin'tHart: Perhaps you could write a full answer with a better solution. ;)

Comment: @dgig Not sure if I follow you. Could you shed some more light? This needs to be part of a relational model as there are other dependent aspects to it.

Comment: I'm not sure what else to say, Magento uses this same design pattern for their system, the idea being it is highly modular, configurable, and extensible. What you're doing is a common pattern (you have to ask Colin why he considers it an anti pattern) and should work well. Yes, your model makes sense. But people have already put a lot of work into similar problems. I suggest you look at what Magento has done to see the common pitfalls.

Comment: @ToC: What do the other dependencies look like? What, exactly, are you having trouble with? Entity-Attribute-Value systems are not new, but they *can* be tricky to work with. Is there a specific problem that you're having difficulties with?

Comment: The intent of my question is to gather ideas so I could 'standardize' my data model. EAV is not a new concept, so I wanted to know if there are any standardized models already. Thanks for all your comments. @dgig: it does not look like it is possible to 'flag' your comment as the answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you are using Postgres have a look into the `hstore` data type. It's a very efficient and fast (indexable!) key/value store which is a much better fit to this problem than the EAV pattern.

Answer (score 2):

What's the question? Does this make sense? Yea, sure.

*1. A product could have more than one attribute* **Fine**
*2. A product could have more than one of the same attribute. A shirt is both 'brown' and 'green'* **Um. If you say so. Sounds a bit strange but that's up to you, I guess.**
*3. All Attributes and its Values have to be pre-defined (loaded from text file)* **Again, sounds a bit strange that numerical fields like weight and length have to have pre-defined values. I personally go for a table of pre-defined values and storing non-predefined values separately, but it makes the structure a LOT more complex. Up to you if you want (or need) to do it this way, really.**
*4. Once the data is loaded (once every few months), there is heavy SELECTing. So the model needs to be read-optimized.* **If it's properly indexed then the fact that you've got a squillion rows shouldn't impact on performance so much.**

Example query to get the product name and attributes for a product:

```
SELECT
Product.ProductID, Product.Name,
Attribute.AttributeID, Attribute.Name,
ProductAttributes.AttributeValueID,
AttributeValue.AttributeValueID, AttributeValue.Value,

FROM
Product
JOIN ProductAttributes ON Product.ProductID = ProductAttributes.productID
JOIN AttributeValue ON ProductAttributes.AttributeValueID = AttributeValue.AttributeValueID
JOIN Attribute ON AttributeValue.AttributeID = Attribute.AttributeID

WHERE Product.ProductID = 1234
```

Index-wise, make sure you've got the usual primary key indexes. You'll also need an index on ProductAttributes.productID. You'll need an index on Attribute.name if you're planning on referring to this field in a query condition (eg get products which have a value for attribute 'weight')

You don't really **need** the AttributeID in the ProductAttributes table, as you've got the AttributeValueID, whose table then links to ProductAttributes. But having it there could conceivably act as a short cut if you were frequently getting a list of Attributes for a product without their values:

```
SELECT
Product.ProductID, Product.Name,
Attribute.AttributeID, Attribute.Name
FROM
Product
JOIN ProductAttributes ON Product.ProductID = ProductAttributes.productID
--THIS JOIN IS NOW NOT REQUIRED...  JOIN AttributeValue ON ProductAttributes.AttributeValueID = AttributeValue.AttributeValueID
--THIS JOIN CAN BE REPLACED BY THE ONE BELOW...  JOIN Attribute ON AttributeValue.AttributeID = Attribute.AttributeID
JOIN Attribute on ProductAttributes.AttributeID = Attribute.AttributeID
WHERE Product.ProductID = 1234
```

@Colin'tHart - you may be right about it not being a good design, but you'll need to explain why for your argument to have any weight.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Business requirements are guiding us to predefine attribute values. We need ID's in all tables, so to complete the data model. Performance is important, data integrity is more important.